# Error python TypeError: 'int' objet is not callable

Tags: python, log

tengo este codigo, que pertenece a un ejercicio de aprendizaje de python:

```
import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


    class Juego2:
        int_num = 0
        intento = 0
        lista_intentos = []
        intentos_permitidos=0

      def __init__(self, intento, lista_intentos, int_num):
          self.intento = intento
          self.lista_intentos = lista_intentos
          self.int_num = int_num


      @classmethod
      def adivinar_numero(self):`introducir el código aquí`
          try:
              self.int_num = int(input("Introduzca un numero:"))
              self.intentos_permitidos = int(input("Introduzca intentos prermitidos:"))
          except Exception as e:
              logging.ERROR("El valor a ingresar debe de ser un entero")
          for x in range(self.intentos_permitidos):
              self.intento = int(input("adivine numero:"))
              self.lista_intentos.append(self.intento)
              if self.intento < self.int_num:
                  self.intentos_permitidos -= 1
                  logging.WARNING("Intento errónero. El número a adivinar es mayor.", 
  self.intentos_permitidos, "intentos disponibles")
              elif self.intento > self.int_num:
                  self.intentos_permitidos -= 1
                  logging.WARNING("Intento errónero. El número a adivinar es menor.", 
  self.intentos_permitidos, "intentos disponibles")
              else:
                  logging.INFO("Ha acertado el numero! Los intentos fueron los siguientes: ", 
  self.lista_intentos)


  Juego2.adivinar_numero()
```

tengo el siguiente código. Estoy intentando meter el log. Para cuando meta por ejemplo una letra en vez de un numero me indique que "el valor debe de ser entero". Pero al intentar ejecutarlo me salta esto como si no pudiese llamar al logging por que falla el int. No entiendo muy bien lo que puede estar mal. Por otra parte me gustaría saber si así esta bien definido el log o como lo tendría que hacer porque encontré algo de documentación por internet. Pero no lo llego a entender muy bien.

```
Introduzca un numero:t
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/aleja/PycharmProjects/Entrega2/Adivina_numero.py", line 21, in adivinar
    self.int_num = int(input("Introduzca un numero:"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 't'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/aleja/PycharmProjects/Entrega2/Adivina_numero.py", line 38, in <module>
    Juego2.adivinar()
  File "C:/Users/aleja/PycharmProjects/Entrega2/Adivina_numero.py", line 24, in adivinar
    logging.ERROR("El valor a ingresar debe de ser un entero")
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Si ejecuto correctamente el programa, no me saca el log que indica que ya ha terminado correctamente y me saca un array con los intentos. ¿En un import se podria meter algun valor como si fuese un print o esto no es posible?

```
Introduzca un numero:10
Introduzca intentos prermitidos:10
adivine numero:10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/aleja/PycharmProjects/Entrega2/Adivina_numero.py", line 38, in <module>
    Juego2.recuperar()
  File "C:/Users/aleja/PycharmProjects/Entrega2/Adivina_numero.py", line 35, in recuperar
    logging.INFO("Ha acertado el numero! Los intentos fueron los siguientes: ", self.lista_intentos)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Existe una función llamada `error()`:

```
> logging.error(msg, *args, **kwargs)¶
> 
>     Logs a message with level ERROR on the root logger. The arguments are interpreted as for debug().
```

y existe una constante llamada ERROR, con valor 40, en el mismo paquete.

Entonces,

- logging.ERROR es un entero

y

- logging.error() es una función

Lo que necesitas es llamar a logging.error()

Comment: Vale, de acuerdo. Me acabas de sacar de un gran apuro. Llevaba un día con esto dándole vueltas y no entendía que podía ser. Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda. Una ultima cosa para mostrar un error por ejemplo como en mi caso cuando metes un numero que sea menor o mayor al introducido. ¿Lo dejarías como print porque al log no se le puede meter la variable numero de intentos y que la interprede verdad? Osea no meterlo en un warning como lo he metido si no dejarlo en un print para que pinte el numero de intentos que quedan. Muchas gracias de antemano